# Single mongo documment finding with express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am new to MongoDB, express. I want to validate a user with his username and password. But my code is not giving any error and executing the "else statement" even when I am using the correct credentials.

Here is the JS file:

```
    app.post('/auth', function(req, res){

    var user = ( db.collection('auth').findOne({name: req.body.username}));
    var pass = ( db.collection('auth').findOne({password: req.body.password}));

    if(user == req.body.username && pass == req.body.password){
        res.send("Credentials Match");
    }else{
        res.send("Wrong Credentials");
    }
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
 <form class="form-signin" action="/auth" method="POST">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required="">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these two lines

```
var user = ( db.collection('auth').findOne({name: req.body.username}));
var pass = ( db.collection('auth').findOne({password: req.body.password}));
```

are representing an asynchronous code, so the `if else` checks will not wait for them to be executed

unless if you ordered `javascript` to wait

you can use `async/await` to enforce the code to wait until the asynchronous part is done

also, you are getting the user name alone then getting the password alone too

so if the user enters his name, but another password rather than his correct one, and this password exists in the db, the login will be done, while it shouldn't

you have to check the user name and password from the same document to avoid that

something like that

```
app.post('/auth', async function(req, res) { // note the async keyword here
    try {
        var user = await db.collection('auth').findOne({ name: req.body.username , password: req.body.password });

        if (user && user.name == req.body.username && user.password == req.body.password) {
            res.send("Credentials Match");
        } else {
            res.send("Wrong Credentials");
        }
        console.log(req.body);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Exception >>\n', err); // log the error
        res.send("Something wrong has happened while checking the credentials");
    }
})
```

hope it helps

Comment: It is now executing the correct credentials but when I am entering the wrong password it is throwing error: "Cannot read property 'name' of null". 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13056) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Comment: I've updated the answer, we have to check if the user exists or not `if (user && user.name == req.body.username && user.pass == req.body.password)`, also we have to add try/catch inside the async function

Comment: I've updated the answer again to add `try/catch` inside the `async` function, could you check it?

Comment: Yes, it's working. You just need to make it "password" instead of "pass".
    if (user && user.name == req.body.username && user.password == 
    req.body.password)

Answer (score 0):

The findOne method returns you a document. Thus a comparison with a string will possibly always fail. What you need to do is to get a document first.

```
var user = db.collection('auth').findOne({name: req.body.username, password: req.body.password});
```

This returns you the user which has the name and password combination you are looking for. Now you just ask if the user us null or a document and on that you can base your if/else.

I would suggest logging your current var user and var password into console (via console.log() method, so that you can see what mistake you were doing.

Then do a print of the line I have provided you with and see what difference it made. Try doing that with "wrong" password and see what return type you get there. This way you can adapt your if/else conditions.

Comment: In node.js, isn't .findOne() async? I think a callback should be passed as the last parameter.